# Erro ao tentar validar campo com required="required"

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Estou tentando validar meus campos com required="required", em vários modais, acontece que a página, possui tabs, e quando tento utilizar o required="required", nem o modal abre(lembrando que os campos que preciso de validação, são textbox, e dropdownlist), aparece o seguinte erro:

> An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable.

Pelo o que entendi, ele está tentando validar os elementos ocultos. Eu precisava que ele validasse os elementos do modal que está em aberto, e não de todos os elementos de uma vez.
Pesquisei muito sobre o assunto, tentei várias alternativas, uma delas foi esse código no form que não deu certo:

```html
<form name="myform" novalidate>
```

Como posso validar o campo em um modal com required ? Todos os modos que encontrei que dizem funcionar, não funcionaram.

Comment: Por favor, coloque o trecho de código com as linhas que o navegador acusa o erro

Comment: Se estiver usando mais de um form na página, dá um nome e id diferenciado para cada e testa.

Comment: Como assim nome e id diferenciado ? não entendi.

Comment: Isso aconteceu comigo ontem. Era um form aberto que eu havia esquecido. É bom também verificar se não esquecemos alguma TAG aberta. Uma div, form, etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se tiver usando o bootstrap pode tentar com o bootstrap valitador
Tem um exemplo de um form na documentação

http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-examples